# EOL error with shutil.move() while trying to search for documents in folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i get this EOL error in line 12 after shutil.move() and I dont know why. I am sure this a super lowkey question, I tried searching it on the web but couldn't find a solution. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
import os
import shutil

path = 'S:/PythonScript test/'

print("documents in" + path + " :")
print(os.listdir(path))


for i in os.listdir(path):
     if ".txt" in i:
          dest = shutil.move("S:/PythonScript test/" +str(i), "S:/2/Text)
     elif ".pptx" in i:
          dest = shutil.move("S:/PythonScript test/" +str(i), "S:/2/PowerPoint)
     elif ".docx" in i:
          dest = shutil.move("S:/PythonScript test/" +str(i), "S:/2/Word)               
     elif ".png" or ".jpg" or ".bmp" in i:
          dest = shutil.move("S:/PythonScript test/" +str(i), "S:/2/pictures)
```

Comment: The code as posted is missing ```"``` to terminate the directory string in each ```shutil.move``` call

Comment: ahh thanks, stupid error as always